# 1 interface, 2 packages, same struct variable names but different json naming conventions

Tags: json, go, struct, interface

I am wondering if it is possible in the below scenario to be able to remove the two "Balance" structs in each package and just use the interface based "Balance" struct somehow for unmarshalling. The issue that I have is that the json structure that comes back from the individual api's for Balance is different so as of right now I am just converting the local Balance structs into the global interface based Balance struct and returning that. This method is not ideal especially for more complex but very similar functions that I have. I am sure there is a better way to do this but could not find anything similar. Thanks in advance.

```
//******************** API Inteface *****************************
//API Interface path: /global/interfaces/apiinterface/apiinterface.go && structs.go
// /global/interfaces/apiinterface/apiinterface.go
type APIInterface interface {
    //.... other interface func(s)
    GetBalance(account string) (balance Balance, err error)
}
// /global/interfaces/apiinterface/structs.go
type Balance struct{
    Available       float64
    Unconfirmed     float64
}


//******************** Library 1 *****************************
//Library 1 path: /library1/library1.go

type jsonResponse struct {
    Success bool            `json:"success"`
    Message string          `json:"message"`
    Result  json.RawMessage `json:"result"`
}
//Library 1 Balance struct /library1/structs.go
type Balance struct {
    Available       float64   `json:"available"` //json name difference <----------
    Unconfirmed     float64   `json:"unconfirmed"` //json name difference <----------
}
//Library 1 GetBalance /library1/library1.go
func (c *Library1) GetBalance(account string) (balance apiinterface.Balance, err error) {

    r, err := c.client.do("getbalance", []interface{}{account})
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    var response jsonResponse
    if err = json.Unmarshal(r, &response); err != nil {
        return
    }
    var tmpBalance Balance //library 1 Balance struct
    err = json.Unmarshal(response.Result, &tmpBalance)
    if err != nil{
        return
    }
    //convert to global apiinterface struct
    balance = apiinterface.Balance{
        Available:tmpBalance.Available,
        Unconfirmed:tmpBalance.Unconfirmed,
    }

    return
}

//******************** Library 2 *****************************
//Library 2 path: /library2/library2.go

type jsonResponse struct {
    Success bool            `json:"success"`
    Message string          `json:"message"`
    Result  json.RawMessage `json:"result"`
}
//Library 2 Balance struct
type Balance struct {
    Available       float64   `json:"total"` //json name difference <----------
    Unconfirmed     float64   `json:"pending"` //json name difference <----------
}
//Library 2 GetBalance
func (c *Library2) GetBalance(account string) (balance apiinterface.Balance, err error) {

    r, err := c.client.do("getbalance", []interface{}{account})
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    var response jsonResponse
    if err = json.Unmarshal(r, &response); err != nil {
        return
    }
    var tmpBalance Balance //library 2 Balance struct
    err = json.Unmarshal(response.Result, &tmpBalance)
    if err != nil{
        return
    }
    //convert to global apiinterface struct
    balance = apiinterface.Balance{
        Available:tmpBalance.Available,
        Unconfirmed:tmpBalance.Unconfirmed,
    }

    return
}
```

Comment: A better way is to create a struct with embedded struct in each local package

Comment: Can you edit to explain better what you want to achieve? The struct conversion seems like not a big deal and you can simplify by just typecasting: balance = apiinterface.Balance(tmpBalance). Is the problem that you have to repeate the GetBalance() code in each library?

Comment: I would like a way to get rid of the Balance struct in each library and keep the global interface version of Balance. The two Balance structs in each library is a duplication of code and I would like to keep things clean and to keep things more uniform to the interface. I am just wondering if there is a different way I can unmarshal to a struct which doesn't necessarily have the same json structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if something like this does what you need:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type jsonResponse struct {
    Success bool    `json:"success"`
    Message string  `json:"message"`
    Result  Balance `json:"result"`
}

type Balance struct {
    Available   float64
    Unconfirmed float64
}

func (b *Balance) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    m := map[string]float64{}
    if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &m); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    for k, v := range m {
        if k == "available" || k == "total" {
            b.Available = v
        } else if k == "unconfirmed" || k == "pending" {
            b.Unconfirmed = v
        }
    }

    return nil
}

func main() {
    tests := []string{
        `{"success":true,"message":"first","result":{"available":42.42,"unconfirmed":0.88}}`,
        `{"success":true,"message":"second","result":{"total":3.14,"pending":0.42}}`,
    }

    for _, t := range tests {
        resp := jsonResponse{}
        if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(t), &resp); err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        fmt.Printf("%+v\n", resp)
    }

}
```

[playground](https://play.golang.org/p/ssxfeniN5s0)

Comment: This is a really good suggestion to allow further adaptation. I will try this tonight and see if I can get it to work in a more universal manner.

Answer (score 0):

you can try somthing like this:

```
type Balance struct {
    *Balance1
    *Balance2
}
```

and then check them with nil, then cast the not nil one to your interface

Comment: This would create a dependency loop because I would have to do an import of each library to the interface.

Comment: cannot load package: import cycle not allowed.. but if I was to move the Balance1 and Balance2 structs over to the interface package similar to your example then I would need to create a balance struct for each library struct type which in turn is redundant in a similar way to what I am using now. It is a good suggestion though. Just not what I am looking for. I am trying to somehow use one struct  and adapt for each library in the interface package to minimize redundancy and maintenance for further library integrations.